# How to bind data to label in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a form in asp.net,where i have some textbox, in which I have taken some input which is stored in the database.  I have created another page where I have taken the same number of label as the textbox.

I want to show the data in the labels that I last entered.

How can i do that?

Code:

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TrishanConnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 coil_id FROM CoilDetails ORDER BY coil_id DESC", con);
con.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

LabeCoilid.Text = ds.ToString();
LabeCoilid.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try instead of

```
LabeCoilid.Text = ds.ToString();
```

this

```
LabeCoilid.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Comment: One more thing: You do not need

    LabeCoilid.DataBind();
Since there is no DataBind Expressions used - you just assigning the value to the property.

Comment: One more suggestion: For the code you posted you will have better performance using ExecuteScalar method of SqlCommand  - this is much faster than filling DataSet

Answer (score 2):

```
 LabeCoilid.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["coil_id"].ToString();
```

You don't need to call DataBind()

Answer (score -1):

```
 string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TrishanConnection"].ConnectionString;
 using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
 {
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 coil_id FROM CoilDetails ORDER BY coil_id DESC", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dt=ds.Table[0]
     }
 }
 LabeCoilid.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
 LabeCoilid.DataBind();
 con.Close();
```

You can change the rows and columns by changing dt,Rows[4][8]